# Cannot get access to my foreign key in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, mysql, html, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a relationship between a 'Project' and a 'Client'. Here are my models..

```
class Client extends Model
{
  public function projects() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project');
  }
}

class Project extends Model
{
  public function clients() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Client');
  }
}
```

In my 'Projects' controllers index method..

```
$projects = Project::all();
return view('project/projects', compact('projects'));
```

And then in my blade file..

```
@foreach($projects as $project)
<div class="project">
  <div class="status pending"></div>
  <p>{{ $project->name }}</p>
  <span>{{ $project->clients->name }}</span>
</div>
@endforeach
```

I get the following error 'Trying to get property of non-object'. New to Laravel, please go easy.

Comment: What you named the foreign key in project table? Is that `clid` or `client_id` or something else?

Comment: 'client_id' I think that is the convention

Comment: If you have `client_id` column in your project table then the code should work as expected also while making project Do you attach the client id with project? Could you dd($project) and show us the result.

Comment: you mean this? Project {#231 ▼
  +timestamps: false
  #fillable: array:12 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  #attributes: array:14 [▶]
  #original: array:14 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}

Comment: Just print the `original` array result

Comment: in the foreach like so? array(14) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(6)
  ["handover_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["name"]=>
  string(8) "i am big"
  ["abbreviation"]=>
  string(2) "sg"
  ["clientName"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["address"]=>
  string(4) "blah"
  ["city"]=>
  string(2) "sg"
  ["state"]=>
  string(2) "sg"
  ["postCode"]=>
  int(0)
  ["country"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["client_id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(10) "2015-11-20"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  NULL
  ["deleted_at"]=>
  NULL
}

Comment: Did you check manually that the client id `1` exists in database?

Comment: yes I did because I manually put together the tables using phpmyadmin. client_id 1 exists and has it's own information. If all the code looks good and you can't see any errors I might just remake the database because I cant think of anything else that could be wrong. My foreign keys are set to index though so everything should work

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

That code sure looks like it would work (or wouldn't work but for a different reason), but I've found that sometimes you need to do something like this for relationships to work like you might expect:

```
$projects = Project::with('clients')->get();
return view('project/projects', compact('projects'));
```

Also note that since `clients` is a HasMany relationship, you'll need to iterate over `$projects->clients` to get at the `->name` attribute of one of them.

Comment: When I use my controller this way:   $projects = Project::with('clients')->get();
      return view('project/projects', compact('projects'));  And try to iterate over the collection like so  @foreach($projects->clients as $project)  I get a new error 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$clients' Does this mean it's a database issue between 'Client and 'Project'?

Comment: If you're iterating over `$project->clients as $project` then `$project` will have the properties of a `Client` model instance. Try `$project->name`, it should be name of a `Client`

Comment: Yea this was my thinking and that I was hoping to see the name of client instead of a project but got thrown the error. I'm assuming '$clients' as undefined property is referring to $project->clients

Comment: It looks like `->clients` is undefined because what you are iterating over is a collection of Clients not Projects, so if you changed it to `@foreach($projects as $project)` then `$project->clients` should be available inside the loop.

Comment: It should have been available, but I naively looked over all the numbers in my client_id row and failed to notice that one of the fields was set to 0. When getting to that point in the iteration it could not make sense of that number because it did not relate to an actual client.

Answer (score 0):

In my client_id column in my projects table, one of the fields was set to 0. So when iterating and getting to that point it failed and that is what my error message was pertaining to.